# Как смонтировать папку саму в себя с параметрами в fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

Почему при первой попытке не применился `noexec`? Как получить такой маунт в `fstab`?

```
# sudo mount -o bind,noexec /var /var
# mount | grep var
/dev/sda3 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime)
# sudo mount -o remount,noexec /var 
# mount | grep var
/dev/sda3 on /var type ext4 (rw,noexec,relatime)
```

Так не прокатило

```
/var                        /var        none        noexec,bind         0 0
```

Так тоже не срабатывает

```
/var /var none bind 0 0
/var /var none remount,noexec 0 0
```

Возможно есть параметр задать начальную папку при монтировании через блочное устройство.

Вообще интересно вытащить каталог из файловой системы сразу, без лишних биндингов.

Comment: четвёртое поле в /etc/fstab служит для указания опций монтирования. в той строке, **где это блочное устройство монтируется**. если уверены, что [ничего не сломается](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=21941) — правьте.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вы немного не поняли. надо смонтировать так (на псевдосинтаксисе) `/dev/sda3/var/ /var noexec 0 0`.

Comment: в приведенном баге делают **такие же 2 маунта** в коментариях. как записать такое правильно в fstab?

Comment: так вы хотите смонтировать каталог, а не файловую систему? программа linux так не умеет (насколько мне известно): с нужными опциями можно смонтировать **файловую систему** (куда-нибудь, куда не жалко), а потом уже можно «сбиндить» из неё каталог туда, куда нужно.

Comment: ну и файл fstab — имеет всё-таки не командный, а декларативный смысл. команду можно выполнить после загрузки другими средствами.

Comment: Файловая система уже смонтирована (`/`), потом она биндится. но без опций

Comment: ну да. **монтируется файловая система**. помедитируйте над этими тремя словами. bind-инг — это **не** монтирование (файловой системы). это просто **отображение** каталога в другое место дерева.

Comment: Это все понятно. Но похоже нет способа записать это декларативно.

Comment: Команда после загрузки не интересно, а в инитрамфс хук делать не хочется так как его в этом случае прийдется поддерживать

Comment: пробовали что-то вроде `/var /var auto defaults,bind,noexec 0 0`?

Comment: да, срабатывает только бинд

Comment: Ну так может следовать идеологии Unix и не придумывать себе проблемы? А именно, создайте раздел, монтируйте его уже как хотите.

Comment: @0andriy, могу привести пару примеров, где создание раздела это головная боль на будующее. Вот был у коллег билинг Карбон. Там они все порезали по разделам, но вот через полгода база данных перестала в свой раздел помещаться, ещё через пару месяцев var/log заполнился на 100% и сервак не стартанул. Там осталась ищё сотня свободных гигов. LVM спасает, но это лишняя работа. Другой пример - VPS за 300 рублей. 10Г жесткий диск резать и так уже мало.Третий пример бездисковый роутер - если нет диска, то и раздел создать негде, только spi. Линукс сейчас в каждом чайнике - и из чайников собирают ботнет

Comment: больше теоретический вопрос. на практике можно взять что есть из типовых решений.

Answer (score 0):

В проекте LFS дается инструкция "монтирования" путей:

```
export LFS=/mnt/lfs
mount -v --bind /dev $LFS/dev
```

- http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/kernfs.html

Comment: а Вы вопрос читали?)